# Linux Equivalent of Windows Hooks

Tags: windows, linux, ipc, signals

I would like to know how to express something like a [windows hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
in Linux.

I have a Linux application with various threads. The main thread currently installed a signal handler for <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, catches it and shuts down the application.

I would like another thread in the application to process the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> event first and then pass on to the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this would be tricky to do.  Unix signals are primitive.

Signals get delivered to a random thread by default.  To get around this the trick usually employed is to block signals in all the threads except one.  The easiest way to do this is to block all the signals in main with `pthread_sigmask`, then create the threads (which will inherit the signal mask), and then have a separate thread that does a `sigwait/sigwaitinfo` on the blocked signals.  This forces the signals to be delivered to that thread.

After consuming the signal in the signal-catching thread you would need to do a `pthread_kill` with main's thread id and the caught signal number to forward the signal to main.  The problem is that main would have it blocked.

You can't really unblock main and block the signal-catching thread before forwarding the signal because it is a race condition - there is nothing stopping a second signal from coming in and the signal-catching thread not seeing it.  That defeats the whole effort.

You could have the signal-thread send a message to main through some other form of IPC (pipe or whatever) saying "caught XX, take appropriate action".  Maybe that is sufficient?

Maybe someone has some clever idea but I suspect the bottom line is that this just isn't how it is normally done in unix.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick (suggested by [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/unix-signals.html)) could be to have a signal handler writing (e.g. a single byte) into a pipe, and have some thread, pr just some event handler (e.g. [g_io_add_watch](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-IO-Channels.html#g-io-add-watch) with GTK) handle the byte.